# Function return type in interface

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I'm new to Angular 2 / Typescript. I'm working around around interfaces in Typescript. I got the point as by using this we can check our type in compile or dev time itself.

I had created a Interface ts file as below with 2 properties and 1 function:

```js
export interface EmpEnities{
    empname : string;
    deptname :string;
    validation();
}
```

My Component :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmpEnities } from './IEmloyee'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    Employees : EmpEnities[] = [
                {empname:'sreekanth',deptname:'xyz',validation(){return 'a'}},
                {empname:'sreekanth',deptname:'xyz',validation(){return false}},
                {empname:'sreekanth',deptname:'xyz',validation(){return true}}
                ]
}
```

I had perfectly got compile time error if any of the three members(2 properties + 1 function) not used.

Now my criteria is: How can I make sure to get error, if my `Validation()` is not returning a bool value.

If you observe in the array of objects, the first `validate()` is returning string and remaining are returning boolean.

Can I specify the return type of the Function declared in Interface?

Comment: Since this is typescript, `validation(): boolean;` should do the trick.

Comment: @Caramiriel Yeah.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export interface EmpEnities{
    empname : string;
    deptname :string;
    validation: () => boolean;
}

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    Employees : EmpEnities[] = [
                {empname:'sreekanth',deptname:'xyz',validation: () => {return 'a' === 'a'}},
                {empname:'sreekanth',deptname:'xyz',validation: () => {return false}},
                {empname:'sreekanth',deptname:'xyz',validation: () => true}
                ]
}
```